# HashSet Java Example

Tags: java, hashset

In Java, I have a set like this:

```
Set<Student> studentsSet = new HashSet<Student>();
```

Can someone give an example of how to use this in an example?

Comment: Is your Set composed of student objects? If yes; override the equals() and hashcode() methods of Student class, using the roll number as the identity. Now just say studentsSet.remove(new Student(3))

Comment: @aquaraga post your comment as an answer for fun, votes and acceptance!

Answer (score 2):

Expounding what I had mentioned as a comment:
Use the `rollNumber` as an identity, in order to implement the `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods. For example, the `Student` class could look like:

```
class Student {
    private int rollNumber;
    private String name;

    public Student(int rollNumber, String name) {
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return rollNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Student other = (Student) obj;
        return (rollNumber == other.rollNumber);
    }

}
```

You could delete a student this way - note that only the roll number will have a bearing on what gets deleted from the set, which is in line with what the `equals` and `hashcode` look for:

```
 Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();
 students.remove(new Student(3, "I don't care what her/his name is!"));
```